# Is it possible to reference generated helm template name from values file

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

While composing helm chart with few sub-charts I've encountered collision. Long story short, I'm creating config with some value, and config name is generated. But subchart expects that generated names to be referenced directly in `Values.yaml` file.

That's actually service with PG database & I'm trying to install `prometheus-postgres-exporter` to enable Prometheus monitoring for the DB. But that's not the point.

So, I have some config for building DB connection string:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ include "myapp.fullname" . }}-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  PG_CONN_STRING: {{ printf "postgresql://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s" .Values.postgresql.postgresqlUsername .Values.postgresql.postgresqlPassword (include "postgresql.fullname" .) .Values.postgresql.service.port .Values.postgresql.postgresqlDatabase  | b64enc | quote }}
```

Okay, that works file. However, when I'm trying to install `prometheus-postgres-exporter`, that requires naming specific secret name where DB connection string can be obtained. I have a problem with that name should be generated, so I can't provide exact value. Not sure, how can I reference that? Obviously, passing same template code doesn't work, since replacement is single-pass, not recursive.

```yaml
prometheus-postgres-exporter:
  serviceMonitor:
    enabled: true
  config:
    datasourceSecret:
      name: "{{ include "myapp.fullname" . }}-secret" # Doesn't work, unfortunatelly
      key: "PG_CONN_STRING"
```

Is there known way to overcome this other than hardcoding values?